# Gmail Authentication with Unity

Tags: gmail, unity-game-engine

I am trying to integrate Oauth - Google with Unity for my game for WebPlayer platform.

Does Unity allow access the web through HttpWebRequest as it is webplayer ?

Would a JS\HTML authentication that would communicate back to unity about user info be a better approach?

Any pointers on how this can be done?